# How to Convert unsigned long int to char to show on LCD in C

Tags: c, microcontroller

I have a variable that should be converted to character to show on LCD, my problem is when I convert this integer to char with `sprintf` it shows wrong number, every number more than 4 lengths shows incorrect It only shows numbers under length 4 correctly.

my microcontroller is **ATmega16a** IDE is **CodeVisionAVR** and the language is **C**

```
unsigned long int username;
char show[20];

unsigned long int ScanKey(void)
{
    unsigned long int num = 0;
    _lcd_write_data(0x0F);
    PORTC .2 = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        PORTD .0 = 0;
        PORTD .1 = 1;
        PORTD .2 = 1;
        delay_ms(5);
        if (PIND .3 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .3 == 0;
            lcd_putchar('1');
            num = (num * 10) + 1;
        }
        else if (PIND .4 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .4 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('4');
            num = (num * 10) + 4;
        }
        else if (PIND .5 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .5 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('7');
            num = (num * 10) + 7;
        }
        else if (PIND .6 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .6 == 0);
            _lcd_write_data(0x10);
            lcd_putchar(' ');
            _lcd_write_data(0x10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        PORTD .0 = 1;
        PORTD .1 = 0;
        PORTD .2 = 1;
        delay_ms(5);
        if (PIND .3 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .3 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('2');
            num = (num * 10) + 2;
        }
        else if (PIND .4 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .4 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('5');
            num = (num * 10) + 5;
        }
        else if (PIND .5 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .5 == 0)
                ;
            lcd_putchar('8');
            num = (num * 10) + 8;
        }
        else if (PIND .6 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .6 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('0');
            num = (num * 10) + 0;
        }

        PORTD .0 = 1;
        PORTD .1 = 1;
        PORTD .2 = 0;
        delay_ms(5);
        if (PIND .3 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .3 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('3');
            num = (num * 10) + 3;
        }
        else if (PIND .4 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .4 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('6');
            num = (num * 10) + 6;
        }
        else if (PIND .5 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .5 == 0);
            lcd_putchar('9');
            num = (num * 10) + 9;
        }
        else if (PIND .6 == 0)
        {
            while (PIND .6 == 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    PORTC .2 = 0;
    _lcd_write_data(0x0C);

    return num;
}

lcd_clear();
lcd_putsf("Enter Username:");
lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
sprintf(show, "%lu", username);
lcd_puts(show);
```

this is not my whole code, it's the part I have a problem with.

i enter this 56321

[image]

the output is this

[image]

https://files.fm/f/qpwrmfs6h this is the video.

and I tried `%ul` and `%lu`, `%ul` have the same problem
and `%lu` output is like this
[image]
[image]

my English is not very well and it is hard for me to add details

Comment: AVR implementation of the "sprintf" does not support long number formats.

Comment: Zavosh, what if you enter `"12345"`?  (5 digits yet less than `INT_MAX`)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ```"12345"``` is ok, it shows correctly

Comment: Zavosh, [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257239/how-to-convert-unsigned-long-int-to-char-to-show-on-lcd-in-c?noredirect=1#comment120634805_68257239) looks correct.  Easy enough to write your own `ulongtoa()`.

Comment: There's something very wrong here.  *If* you were using 16-bit two's complement signed integers, the maximum value would be 32767, and 56321 would not be representable, and the bit pattern would correspond to -9215. *But*, you've specified `unsigned long`, and you're using `%lu`, so this should work just fine.  It looks like, as 0___________ 9 has suggested, your `sprintf` is broken.

Comment: @SteveSummit it seems ```sprintf``` doesn't support long number format

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what weird defines do you have that makes `PORTD .2 = 0;` or `PIND .6 == 0` valid syntax.

Comment: Z, Might as well make certain other code is not wrong, just `sprintf()`.  Try `sprintf(show, "%lu", 56321L);`.

Comment: Do you use large integers in your program? If you only use such "integers" for username and password, then those values should not be integers anyway. They are normally strings and should be handled as strings.

Comment: @HAL9000 ```PORTD .2 = 0;``` means the second port of D ports of atmega16 microcontroller.

Comment: @Gerhard, I want to expand on your comment. In some  languages, and I assume also English, "Number" and "Value" are not the same thing. A "number" is a series of digits, a "value" is how much you have of something. A number is useful for encoding values, but it doesn't mean there is a one-to-one mapping between them. For instance "123" and "0123" are different numbers, but they encode the same value. In C `int` is useful for storing values,  but not numbers. Strings are typically more useful for numbers.

Comment: @ZavoshGhorbanpour, I was able to guess the semantics of `PORTD .2`, that is was the second (or third?) port of something. But that was not what I was curios about. If `PORT` is an identifier, then `PORTD .2` is not valid C syntax. So I assume `PORTD` is a hackish `#define` with operators that turns a floating point value into a port access.

Comment: Store as (short fixed-size) strings?

Comment: Does your program need the username as an `unsigned long` value? I suggest to store the value in an array of `char` either instead of in addition to storing it as a number. As a compromise to save memory compared to a string and to save expensive operations compared to binary values you could store the number as BCD. For example the input `456321` can be stored as 0x00456321, if necessary in combination with the number of valid digits, which is 6 in this example. This would avoid multiplication or division by 10 by using much simpler bit operations.

Comment: Subtract your first input number from 65535.  Figure it out.  Then read the datasheet for your part and learn the sizes of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use `printf` and `scanf` functions in the 8 bits environment. They are resources greedy and are not very suitable for this kind of micros.
2. `printf` and `scanf` implementations are limited and do not support many formats.
3. 32bits numbers operations are very expensive (especially division) in the 8 bits environment - try to use 16 bits where possible

```
#define MASK32ULONG 1000000000UL
#define MASK16UINT  10000

char *toDecimal(char *buff, unsigned long val)
{
    unsigned long mask = MASK32ULONG;
    unsigned long remain;
    char *wrk = buff;

    do
    {
        int digit = val / mask;

        if(digit || !val) *wrk++ = '0' + digit;
        val %= mask;
        mask /= 10;
    }while(val);
    *wrk = 0;
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand this snippet, given that it is quite hot and its been a really long day so far, would you be so kind as to explain it to me @0___________ ? 
Especially this  part *wrk++ = '0' + digit; and what the return of buff actually achieves? I think I have been blinded by looking at this for to long :)

Comment: `int digit` will be a value `0 - 9` to convert that to the ASCII digit representation for the number you add `'0'` to it so you have a proper ASCII digit. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) Another way to think of it is you are converting decimal `0` to the value `48` which corresponds to the ASCII Digit `'0'`. (and so on and so forth for `1-9`)

Answer (score 0):

use %lu then go to project->configure->c compiler then change (s)printf to long,width,precision

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).